# Groovy Pattern for matching a value in map

Tags: groovy, pattern-matching, intellij-plugin, ofbiz

Hy guys, i'm working on a IDEA plugin and custom references. I have many references working, but i'm stuck with a difficult one.

I'd like to detect patterns in groovy such as this one :

```
result = run service: 'createAgreementItem', with: createAgreementItemInMap
```

In the above line, i'd like to get the `createAgreementItem` element to match.

`run` is defined in a groovy base script

```
package org.apache.ofbiz.service.engine
abstract class GroovyBaseScript extends Script {
    //...
    Map run(Map args) throws ExecutionServiceException {
        return runService((String)args.get('service'), (Map)args.get('with', new HashMap()))
    }
    //...
```

The problem is, what i'm trying to get isn't technically a parameter, it's a value from a map with the key equals to `service`.
So this won't work :

```
GroovyPatterns.groovyLiteralExpression()
        .methodCallParameter(0,
                GroovyPatterns.psiMethod().withName("run")
                        .definedInClass("org.apache.ofbiz.service.engine.GroovyBaseScript"))
```

Do you have any ideas or any help ? Thanks in advance !

EDIT :
Actually, i'm looking for a doc or an example for any use of the `org.jetbrains.plugins.groovy.lang.psi.patterns.GroovyPatterns`
library.
I don't get it, maybe i'm not familiar enough with groovy though i used it a bit.
Any help welcome on this.

Answer (score 0):

> The problem is, what i'm trying to get isn't technically a parameter,
> it's a value from a map with the key equals to "service"

If all you want to do is retrieve the `service` value from the `Map` then instead of `args.get('with', new HashMap())` you could do `args.with.service`.  If you wanted null safety, you could do `args?.with?.service`.

Comment: Maybe my problem wasn't clear enough. I'm not working on the groovy DSL `run` method. I'm working on the IDEA groovy pattern

Comment: Apologies.  I thought you wanted to know how to get the value out of the `Map` that is associated with the `service` key.

Comment: No problem at all, thanks for answering anyway :D